# How to use variables inside LinearGradient initializer - SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, linear-gradients

Im trying to do this inside a structure that uses cardGradient later down the code. "1a" and "1b" are colors inside the assets folder.

```
var color1 = "1a"
var color2 = "1b"

let cardGradient = LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: 
[Color(color1), Color(color2)]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)
```

> Cannot use instance member 'color1' within property initializer;
>   property initializers run before 'self' is available.
>
> Cannot use instance member 'color2' within property initializer;
>   property initializers run before 'self' is available

//

> Solution: Thanks for the help!

```
var color1 = "1a"
var color2 = "1b"

VStack {
     // ... some views here
}
.background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: 
[Color(color1), Color(color2)]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
```

Comment: You can make it a lazy var: `lazy var cardGradient = ...`

Comment: @Liv Welcome to StackOverflow! If an answer below helped you figure out a solution, you should accept it. If you believe your solution is unique enough to warrant its own answer, you can answer your own question with your solution and accept it. That way, programmers with a similar problem will know what worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how intensive creating a `LinearGradient` is on a phone, but if that's not an issue, you can just make `LinearGradient` a computed variable:

```
var color1 = "1a"
var color2 = "1b"

let cardGradient: LinearGradient {
    LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color(color1), Color(color2)]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)
}
```

If it is intensive on computing resources, you can .make it optional (or give it a default value) and set it in the `.onAppear` of a view, but then you would have to make the gradient `@State`:

```
var color1 = "1a"
var color2 = "1b"
@State var cardGradient: LinearGradient?

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        // ... some views here
    }.onAppear {
        self.cardGradient = LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color(color1), Color(color2)]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that both these solutions aren't particularly great for if the colors often change, but you don't want to gradient to update when the colors change, however it doesn't sound like that is an issue for you. If you see lag with the first option, use the second one.

Comment: Im planing to implement a feature that allows the user change the color background of some views. i want them to be able to choose from a preset of gradient colors and change the views' colors at any given moment. Xcode wont allow me to use variables inside LinearGradient, which would make it simple to update the gradient colors

Comment: Did you try what I said to try? The Xcode error is happening because you cannot use instance members (the color variables) within a property initializer (when you are initializing the gradient). My two solutions work around this by either making the gradient computed, so it doesn't use the color variables until it is accessed, or by setting its value in the onAppear, which is executed after the color variables are initialized.

Comment: I've tested it out and both of my solutions work (unless your assests are incorrect, but I have no way of testing that).